# Excel - Finding max value with previous row and various range size

Tags: python, excel, vba, max

I need to find the maximum relative humidity value during precipitation events. I have calculated the duration of each event and was able to get excel to “scan” the event going backward. The issue where I am stuck at is that some events start on the previous day and I don’t know how to get excel to scan the previous row.

Here is an example…

[image: Example image]

code:

```
=IF(AND(Duration!BP3>0), MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, COLUMN(C3)-Duration!BP3)):C3),0)
```

**Example:** First event in the above table was only an hour long (L2) so the max value is automatically 90.

The next event has a duration of 11 hours. I am trying to get excel to find the max value from 21z to 02z. So BP3 = 6. Since BP3 is greater than 0, I try to find the max relative humidity by subtracting the duration to get a range of the event (COLUMN(C3)-Duration!BP3). For this event, the max value would be 100.

**Problem:** I get "#VALUE!" because there is no cell with =(C3-6). Is there a way to get it to scan the previous row as well? Would a VBA or python code work better? I am fairly new to VBA and python so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(BP3<COLUMN(C3),MAX(OFFSET(C3,0,-(BP3-1),1,BP3)),MAX(MAX(A3:C3),MAX(OFFSET(X3,-1,-BP3+COLUMN(C3)+1,1,BP3-COLUMN(C3)))))
```

If BP3 isn't too big, take the max of C3 offset backward. If it is too big, take the max of two ranges: The first range is A3:C3. The second range is X3, offset up 1 row and back a number of columns (bp3-column(c3)).

If the event spans more than two rows, this won't work.

Comment: Thank you! I have never heard of/used offset before. Works better than the indirect/address function